# Tres números del vector igual al anterior

Tags: java

Hoy estoy intentando hacer un nuevo ejercicio, en el cual básicamente quiero que: si el número es igual al anterior 3 veces, me cambie estos tres números repetidos por 9 (por ejemplo).

Pero me sale el error de:

> java.lang.ArrayIndexOutOfBoundsException

```
/**
 * @param args the command line arguments
 */
 public static void main(String[] args) {
    Scanner entrada = new Scanner(System.in);
    Random random = new Random();
    System.out.println("Di la grandaria del vector");
    int grandaria = entrada.nextInt();
    int[] dades = new int[grandaria];
    for (int i = 0; i < dades.length; i++) {
        dades[i] = random.nextInt(2) + 1;
    }

    System.out.print("Fila: ");
    for (int i = 0; i < dades.length; i++) {
        System.out.print(dades[i] + " ");

    }
    System.out.println("");
    System.out.print("Resultado: ");
    for (int i = 0; i < grandaria; i++) {
        if (dades[i] == dades[i - 0] && dades[i] == dades[i -1] && dades[i] == dades[i -2]) {
            dades[i - 0] = 9;
            dades[i - 1] = 9;
            dades[i - 2] = 9;

          }
          System.out.print(dades[i] + " ");
      }

    }

}
```

Comment: Hola, dices: ***el número es igual al anterior 3 veces***, pero realmente lo que haces en el código es *el número es igual a los 3 anteriores*. ¿Puedes aclarar eso?

Comment: Básicamente que si la secuencia del vector es: 1 2 3 4 4 4 5 6 7 8, me cambie los tres 4 por 9. Es decir, si i = a i-0, i-1 e i-2 me los cambie a 9.

Comment: Que tal! No comprendo bien el planteamiento que haces, y realmente no se si la respuesta que colocaste sea la correcta, verás tu dices que si la secuencia 1 2 3 4 4 4 5 6 7 8 deberá cambiarte los tres 4 por 9. Si no me equivoco solo deberá cambiarte dos de los tres 4, ya que el primero no es igual al anterior.

Comment: Tal vez puedas ser aun más explicito en el planteamiento, debido a lo que mencionas de:  **si el número es igual al anterior 3 veces, me cambie estos tres números repetidos por 9**

Answer (score 0):

```
    System.out.print("Fila: ");
    for (int i = 0; i < dades.length; i++) {
        System.out.print(dades[i] + " ");

    }
    System.out.println("");
    System.out.print("Resultado: ");
    for (int i = 2; i < grandaria; i++) {
        if (dades[i] == dades[i -1] && dades[i] == dades[i -2]) {
            dades[i] = 9;
            dades[i - 1] = 9;
            dades[i - 2] = 9;

        }
    }
        for (int j = 0; j < grandaria; j++) {  
        System.out.print(dades[j] + " ");
    }

}
```

Comment: Solucionado. Tenía un fallo en el for e if, ya que quería llegar a una posición inexistente.